# Simple $M_n(D)$-module with $D$ a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, division-algebras

Define $D$ to be a division algebra over a field $k$ and $R=M_n(D)$ the $n\times n$ matrix ring over $D$. A simple $R$-module $M$ is the quotient of $R$. I can write $R=\bigoplus_j I_j$ where $I_j$ is the subring of $R$ all of whose columns except the $j$-th are zero.

Is it true that the induced map $R\to M$ induces an isomorphism between $M$ and some $I_j$?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that "yes, $M$ is isomorphic to $I_j$ (for any $j$!), but it is not necessarily 'induced' by a projection $R\to M$."

Given any simple left module $S$, a projection $\phi: R\to S$ turns into an isomorphism $R\ker\phi\cong S$. Where $\ker\phi$ is a maximal left ideal of $R$. Since $R$ is semisimple, $R\cong \ker\phi\oplus N$ where $N$ is a left ideal of $R$. So $S\cong R/\ker\phi=(N\oplus\ker\phi)/\ker\phi\cong N$.

This shows that every simple left module appears as a minimal left ideal of $R$. **But $N$ need not be one of the $I_j$.** For example, $N$ could be the set of matrices which have an arbitrary first column, the second column identical with the first, and the rest of the columns zero. There are *lots* of other simple left ideals of $R$ other than the $I_j$.

To prove that all simple left $R$ modules are mutually isomorphic, we can use this

**Lemma**: For a fixed minimal left ideal $N<R$, the sum $I_N=\sum\{N'<R\mid N\cong N'\}$ is an ideal of $R$ ($N'$ denotes a left ideal, of course.) Furthermore, if $L$ is another minimal left ideal which is nonisomorphic to $N$, then $I_L\cap I_N=\{0\}$.

Since $R$ is simple, only one such $I_N$ can exist, and that means there is only one isotype of simple left $R$ module. That is why all of the $I_j$ in your original post are mutually isomorphic, and indeed every other simple left $R$ module you find is going to be isomorphic to these also.

Comment: Your answer is much appreciated.  with regards

Comment: Great answer! Do you by any chance have a reference for that lemma’s proof?

Comment: Also, what does “isotype” in this context mean? I’ve looked up the term but the definition I’ve found is referring to Lie algebras.

Comment: @dahemar Theorem 14.14 in Martin Isaacs' *Algebra: a graduate course* is one.  Isotype just means an equivalence class of mutually isomorphic right modules.

Comment: Hi! I don’t get the $(N\oplus\ker\phi)/\ker\phi\cong N$ step, could you please explain it?

Comment: @kejihiv It's the isomorphism you get from applying the first homomorphism theorem to the projection $(n, k)\mapsto n$

Comment: Thanks! One last question, why do you say that $R$ is semisimple in the second paragraph, then that it’s simple in the last one?

Comment: @kejihiv because I’m using the relevant property when it’s needed. Because the ring is semisimple, that direct sum exists (that is not a property of simple rings).  Because the ring is simple, there’s only one isoclass of simple module (that is not true of some semisimple rings.)

Answer (score 2):

> $R=M_n(D)$ the $n\times n$ matrix ring over $D$. 
>  $I_j$ is the
> subring of $R$ all of whose columns except the $j$-th are zero.

There is another way to prove that any simple left $R$-module is isomorphic to $I_1$. We divide the proof into two parts.

- First, we show that any simple left $R$-module is isomorphic to some
  simple left $R$-**submodule** of  $_RR$ (equivalently, minimal left
  ideal of $R$).
- Second, we show that any simple left $R$-submodule of $_RR$ is
  isomorphic to $I_1$ .

For the first part: let $S$ be a simple left $R$-module. One can check that $S$ is cyclic and say $x$ is its generator. It's easy to construct a non-zero epimorphism $R \to Rx = S$. Since $R$ is semisimple, the epimorphism splits.(See Corollary 13.10 in *Rings and Categories of Modules 2ed*) Hence $S$ is isomorphic to some simple left $R$-submodule of $_RR$.

For the second part: let $T$ be a simple left $R$-submodule of $_RR$. Since $T\ne0$, there must exist some integer $w$ and matrix $A \in T$ such that the $w$-th colunm of $A$ is not $0$. Without lose of generality, let's say $w = 1$. Then we construct a non-zero $R$-module homorphism $T \to I_1$ that only preserves the first column of matrices in $T$. Since $I_1$ is also simple, by Schur's lemma, we have $T \cong I_1$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not add anything to rschwieb's one from the theoretical point of view. However, for didactic reasons, I had to prove that any simple $\mathsf{Mat}_n(D)$-module is isomorphic to $D^n$ directly (and by elementary arguments). The following is the argument I found and I think can be interesting for our community herein.

Set $R=\mathsf{Mat}_n(D)$, for the sake of simplicity. Let $V$ be a simple $R$-module. It can be easily checked that there exists $v\neq 0$ in $V$ such that $Rv = V$. In particular, there exists an $E_{ij}$ such that $E_{ij}v \neq 0$, where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with $1$ in $(i,j)$-th position and $0$ elsewhere. Consider the assignment
$$
\phi:D^n \to V, \qquad \begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \sum_k a_kE_{kj}v = 
\underset{j\text{-th column}}{\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 & a_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & a_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & a_n & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}}}v.
$$
We have that for every $\begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix} \in D^n$,
$$
\phi\left((x_{ij})\begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix}\right) = \phi\begin{pmatrix} \sum_i x_{1,i}a_i \\ \vdots \\ \sum_i x_{n,i}a_i\end{pmatrix} = \sum_k \sum_i x_{k,i}a_iE_{kj}v = \left((x_{ij})\left(\sum_k a_kE_{kj}\right)\right)v = (x_{ij})\left(\left(\sum_k a_kE_{kj}\right)v\right) = (x_{ij})\phi\begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix},
$$
that is to say, $\phi$ is $R$-linear. In addition, $\phi$ is not zero (because $\phi(e_i) = E_{ij}v \neq 0$) and it is an $R$-module homomorphism between simple $R$-modules, whence it has to be an isomorphism.